# How to use kinect data to run RGBDSLAM over multiple machines?

Tags: slam, navigation, kinect, turtlebot, rgbd6dslam

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello, I want to use turtlebot to run RGBDSLAM: use a laptop connected kinect camera to obtain depth data and color data, and then through a wireless way to send the depth data and color data  to the workstation side of the desktop, and then on the workstation side running RGBDSLAM. However, I encountered some problems.

1.on the workstation ssh -X turtlebot@IP_OF_TURTLEBOT

2. on the turtlebot: roslaunch openni_camera openni_node.launch
3. on the workstaion: rosrun rviz rviz

and i set the "FIxed frame : /openni_camera", and i can use rviz to see the depth data"/camera/depth/image_raw"  and color data "/camera/rgb/image_mono".
but the color data and the depth data seems not synchronized.when i got 2 depth data ,1 color data i got.

4. i want to use the color data and depth data in RGBDSLAM. and on the workstaion : rosrun rgbdslam rgbdslam     the GUI Appear. but  it always sits with blank screens in a 'waiting for image/motion' state.
5. in the web [link text](http://answers.ros.org/question/37513/running-rgbdslam-over-multiple-machines/)    i set the  "subscriber_queue_size"  to a high value. The situation is still the same.

PS: my turtlebot laptop 32bit ubuntu 11.10. Electric
workstaion  desktop 64bit ubuntu 11.10  Electric
Thanks in advance

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/67626/how-to-use-kinect-data-to-run-rgbdslam-over-multiple-machines?/) by [longzhixi123](https://answers.ros.org/users/3030/longzhixi123/) on ROS Answers with karma: 78 on 2013-07-17

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [yincanben](https://answers.ros.org/users/20734/yincanben/) on 2014-11-19**:
Have you solved this problem?I want to run rgbdslam over multiple machines.Can you give some advices?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Wireless is slow, many images are therefore dropped. This leads to badly synchronized images. RGBDSLAM uses the [approximate time synchronizer](http://www.ros.org/wiki/message_filters/ApproximateTime) to pair color and depth image (and camera info). I assume that the synchronization of the respective images is too bad to find pairs.

My suggestions:

- Reduce bandwidth by using the monochrome image instead of rgb-color
- Reduce bandwidth using [qvga](http://answers.ros.org/question/61689/problem-with-rgbdslam-and-qvga-resolution/) resolution.
- Avoid the unsynchronized dropping of messages: Write and run a proxy node on the robot that combines color image, depth image and camera info in a custom message and sends that. Then on the other machine, write a proxy that splits the message and sends it again on three topics to rgbdslam. Then either all or nothing is dropped.

---

Originally posted by [Felix Endres](https://answers.ros.org/users/113/felix-endres/) with karma: 6468 on 2013-07-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2